# Activity Fence not working in Awareness API

Tags: android, google-awareness

I tried implementing the Activity Fence using the Google Awareness API. But changes in the user's activity are not getting detected. The headphone fence works as expected though.

**ActivityFenceActivity**

```
public class ActivityFenceActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks {

private static final String FENCE_RECEIVER_ACTION = "FENCE_RECEIVE";
private static final String FENCE_WALKING_KEY = "walkingKey";
private static final String FENCE_RUNNING_KEY = "runningKey";
private static final String TAG = ActivityFenceActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
private TextView activityTextView;
private BroadcastReceiver activityFenceReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Recieved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        FenceState fenceState = FenceState.extract(intent);

        if (TextUtils.equals(fenceState.getFenceKey(), FENCE_WALKING_KEY)) {
            switch (fenceState.getCurrentState()) {
                case FenceState.TRUE:
                    activityTextView.setText("User is walking");
                    break;
                case FenceState.FALSE:
                    activityTextView.setText("User is not walking");
                    break;
                case FenceState.UNKNOWN:
                    activityTextView.setText("Activity state unknown");
                    break;
            }
        } else if (TextUtils.equals(fenceState.getFenceKey(), FENCE_RUNNING_KEY)) {
            switch (fenceState.getCurrentState()) {
                case FenceState.TRUE:
                    activityTextView.setText("User is running");
                    break;
                case FenceState.FALSE:
                    activityTextView.setText("User is not running");
                    break;
                case FenceState.UNKNOWN:
                    activityTextView.setText("Activity state unknown");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity_fence);

    activityTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.activityTextView);

    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(ActivityFenceActivity.this)
            .addApi(Awareness.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .build();
    googleApiClient.connect();

    findViewById(R.id.register_fence).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            registerActivityFence();
        }
    });

    findViewById(R.id.unregister_fence).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            unregisterActivityFence();
        }
    });


}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable final Bundle bundle) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Google API connected");

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(final int i) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Google API connection suspended");

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    registerReceiver(activityFenceReceiver, new IntentFilter(FENCE_RECEIVER_ACTION));
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    unregisterReceiver(activityFenceReceiver);
    unregisterActivityFence();
}

private void registerActivityFence() {
    AwarenessFence walkingFence = DetectedActivityFence.during(DetectedActivityFence.WALKING);
    AwarenessFence runningFence = DetectedActivityFence.during(DetectedActivityFence.RUNNING);

    PendingIntent fencePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,
            0,
            new Intent(FENCE_RECEIVER_ACTION),
            0);

    Awareness.FenceApi.updateFences(googleApiClient, new FenceUpdateRequest.Builder()
            .addFence(FENCE_WALKING_KEY, walkingFence, fencePendingIntent).build())
            .setResultCallback(new ResultCallbacks<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(@NonNull final Status status) {
                    Toast.makeText(ActivityFenceActivity.this,
                            "Fence registered successfully",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull final Status status) {
                    Toast.makeText(ActivityFenceActivity.this,
                            "Cannot register activity fence.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

    Awareness.FenceApi.updateFences(googleApiClient, new FenceUpdateRequest.Builder()
            .addFence(FENCE_RUNNING_KEY, runningFence, fencePendingIntent).build());

}

private void unregisterActivityFence() {
    Awareness.FenceApi.updateFences(
            googleApiClient,
            new FenceUpdateRequest.Builder()
                    .removeFence(FENCE_WALKING_KEY)
                    .removeFence(FENCE_RUNNING_KEY)
                    .build()).setResultCallback(new ResultCallbacks<Status>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(@NonNull Status status) {
            Toast.makeText(ActivityFenceActivity.this,
                    "Fence unregistered successfully.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Status status) {
            Toast.makeText(ActivityFenceActivity.this,
                    "Cannot unregister headphone fence.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

}

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.subhrajyoti.awareness">

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.awareness.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBEmjlfC87xRUP2FnFynsDdY3QRuI1hIHs" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Have you tried to add the STILL Fence to check if this fence gets fired?

Comment: I am encountering the same issue. I am trying to react to changes in the users activity, but somehow it is only triggered once and then never again. Did you ever manage to get any insight?

Answer (score 0):

If the headphone fence is working and the activity fence is not, maybe you simply forgot to add the permission in the manifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION"/>
```

Comment: I have included the permission too. For some reason it wasn't getting displayed in the question. I've updated it

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use Awareness API instead of geofencing, I think the problem is how you tested your code. 
I'm pretty sure that Awareness uses phone's sensors, so when I use the GPS simulator to simulate a walk, it doesn't trigger anything, but if I use my real phone and walk, BroadcastReceiver is triggered. 
However, I don't know how to simulate a "sensor walking" on the emulator!